# Add description to files uploaded by the Media file selector widget

Tags: 7, entities, media

I am using D7 with media module. I have a field for (multiple) files.

Instead of the built in "file" widget for the file field, I am using the "Media file selector" widget.

In drupal core's "file" widget, I am able to select the "Enable Description field" option to label the files. I am unable to find such an option with the "media file selector"

There is a whole section to add files with many fields. But I am looking for a field with some sort of description or title option. I will use it as the link text, instead of the file name.

Is there an option somewhere that I've been missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the file_entity module you can add fields to files.  So in your case add a "Description" field to your image file type.

When selecting how the field will be rendered, make sure to choose "Rendered file" and it display the file with the extra fields.

Comment: yes, there is such a setting and I added a description field to the audio file type but still the description field is not available upon upload (or later).

Comment: Make sure that you are using the file_entity-2.x-dev and media-2.x-dev